# Reuse datagridview (unregister events)

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I'm having some problems with resetting event handlers to my datagridviews in a project I'm working on.

I have a number of datagridviews that I fill with values from a testing device hooked up to a serial port.
When a testing session is complete I would like to reset the datagridviews for a new session.

My problem is that I have registered events for cell clicks on each cell created and that event persist when i clear the datagridviews.

I am setting the values in the datagridview programmatically

Here is how I add the cellclick events:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < dgList.Count ; i++) //dgList is list of datagridviews
{
    int numberForEvent = i; //i is datagrid nr i

    dgList[i].CellClick += ((sender, e) =>
    {
         alterValueClick(numberForEvent, e.RowIndex);
    });
}
```

It works fine the first time I use my program but if I reset the datagrids for a new test session the events get registered twice and so on.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to clear the events or am I going the wrong way about my design?

Comment: The events don't belong to the cells but to the dgv. Clear them 1-by1-1 or create new grids.

Comment: Sorry, by reset i mean to iterate over the datagrids and use .rows.clear and .columns.clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> by reset i mean to iterate over the datagrids and use .rows.clear and .columns.clear

Clearing the rows and columns won't un-register the event. You have two options

```
- either re-initialize DataGrid and re-register the event 

- un-register previous event and re-register new one.
```

By the way, why do you need to reset the event? why not use the already registered events?

**Edit**

I don't think you can un-register the click event here because of the way you are declaring it. It is an anonymous method it won't be un-registered like this

try assigning event handler a solid method and it should work

```
//for registering
dgList[i].CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(YourMethod);

//for unregistering
dgList[i].CellClick -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(YourMethod);
```

Then just like you are registering inside for loop, run a for loop for un-registering as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason i need to reset the event is that the I sometimes hide a number of the datagrids depending on how many values i need from the testing equipment. It has to do with the way i store the values. Any ides on how to unregister the events?

Comment: Thanks again! I managed to get it to work using your first suggestion, to re-initialize the datagrids. I tried to create a separate method but couldn't supply the value for i as an argument. I'm pretty new to windows forms :)